# Issue after upgrading cakephp from 1.3 to 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, upgrade

When I upgrade cakephp from 1.3 to 2.0, I am getting below error.
I am not using any plugins.

I tried to added `CakePlugin::load('User');`  and CakePlugin::loadAll(); in the `bootstrap.php` file. But still getting same error.

Pleaes help.

Missing Plugin

```
Error: The application is trying to load a file from the User plugin

Error: Make sure your plugin User is in the app/Plugin directory and was loaded

<?php
CakePlugin::load('User');
```

Loading all plugins: If you wish to load all plugins at once, use the following line in your app/Config/bootstrap.php file

`enter code here`CakePlugin::loadAll();

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_plugin.ctp
Stack Trace

```
CORE/Cake/Core/App.php line 365 → CakePlugin::path(string)
CORE/Cake/Core/App.php line 226 → App::pluginPath(string)
CORE/Cake/Core/App.php line 547 → App::path(string, string)
[internal function] → App::load(string)
[internal function] → spl_autoload_call(string)
CORE/Cake/Utility/ClassRegistry.php line 145 → class_exists(string)
CORE/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php line 163 → ClassRegistry::init(string, boolean)
CORE/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php line 196 → FormHelper->_getModel(string)
CORE/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php line 346 → FormHelper->_introspectModel(string, string)
APP/View/Users/profile.ctp line 49 → FormHelper->create(string, array)
CORE/Cake/View/View.php line 929 → include(string)
CORE/Cake/View/View.php line 891 → View->_evaluate(string, array)
CORE/Cake/View/View.php line 460 → View->_render(string)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 952 → View->render(null, null)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 192 → Controller->render()
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 160 → Dispatcher->_invoke(UsersController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/webroot/index.php line 108 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Line number 49 if  APP/View/Users/profile.ctp

```
   <?php echo $this->Form->create("User.user_profile_data", array("action" => "/users/profile")); ?>
```

User Model

```
<?php
 class User extends AppModel {
var $name = 'users';
var $hasMany = array('Group' =>
    array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        ));

function changeDataSource($newSource) {
    parent::setDataSource($newSource);
    parent::__construct();
}

function validateLogin($data) {

     $user = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('username' => $data['User']['username'], 'password' => $data['User']['password'], 'status' => 'A')));


    if (empty($user) == false)
        return $user;
    return false;
   }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you add the code for ``APP/View/Users/profile.ctp`` around line 49?

Comment: Edit your original post and please take care of formatting. Also add your ``User`` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove any plugin load while you are not using any plugin. then modify your line #49 :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create("User", array("action" => "/users/profile")); ?>
```

The way that you have set it `User.blahBlah` tells CakePHP to treat it as a plugin.

For reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: Great!. It is fixed. Thank you sємsєм :)

Comment: @VipinPA You are welcome. don't forget to set it as answer and vote it up. :)

Comment: I can't vote now :( . Only 6 reputations. Definitely do it once I get 15 reputations :)